# Time series with same variables but different respondents

Tags: time-series, causality

I would like to measure the impact of an intervention using a form of time series or some related technique (like segmented regression).  I would like to use the Schools and Staffing Survey, which assesses my variable of interest over time, however, the respondents are different at each time point. I assume different respondents would present a problem for this kind of analysis.  Can anyone suggest another technique that would allow me to gauge the impact of the intervention?

Answer (score 2):

The data you have is sometimes called repeated cross section data. 
There are techniques that can be used with this kind of data. You can have a look at the Difference-in-Difference estimators (and their "matching" variants) presented by [Blundell and Costa Dias (2000)](http://ideas.repec.org/a/ifs/fistud/v21y2000i4p427-468.html) as well as [Smith and Todd (2005)](http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/econom/v125y2005i1-2p305-353.html). There are some assumptions to be fulfilled. It's your role to check this and to argue that these estimators can be applied.

For a really complete picture, you can have a look at [Heckman, Lalonde and Smith (2001)](http://ideas.repec.org/h/eee/labchp/3-31.html).