# time series with multiple respondents of same variables

Tags: regression, time-series

I have some time series data consisting of several people with certain indexes according to time. It looked like this:

```
person 1
time index1 index2
9:05   3.2    40
9:25   5.0    30
9:55   4.1    50
...
person 2
time index1 index2
9:10   4.5    20
9:30   3.8    60
9:50   4.2    40
...
```

The time interval is same however the start time, duration time and the end time is different.

The goal is to estimate index2 based on time and index1.

I believe there is certain pattern behind the data in total, say there should be similar cycles and trends but got stuck since what I often confronted was simply one person situation with exact start time and end time. What should I do to deal with this kind of time series problem or any guidance I could refer to? Any help will be appreciated.

Questions maybe related:

[Time series with same variables but different respondents](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18585/time-series-with-same-variables-but-different-respondents)

[Estimating same model over multiple time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/estimating-same-model-over-multiple-time-series)